# PowerShell hashtable storage for categorical data

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, nested, hashtable

I have data that is in the structure of indented text along the lines of:

"Subject"

\t"Category"

\t\t"Subcategories"

```
e.g. for two records I would have 

"Planet of the Apes"
\t"Scifi"
\t\t"Movie"
\t\t"TV series"
\t"Popular"
\t\t"Remake"
\t\t"Cult Classic"

BBC News
\t"Topical"
\t\t"Daily News"
\t"Geographical"
\t\t"UK"
\t\t"England"

ITV News
\t"Topical"
\t\t"Daily News"
\t\t"UK"
\t"Geographical"
\t\t"UK"
\t\t"England"
```

(please excuse the formatting, tab or white-space delimited illustrated is made somewhat harder due to automatic formatting in Stackoverflow!

I'm trying to work out the best way to convert this into something I can work with to filter and sort. Since the data currently is plain text, I've got an if statement that works out if it's a Subject, Category, or Subcategory but what would be the most sensible way to build a hashtable out of data like this?

```
$processedData = @{}
$versionattribs | ForEach-Object{
if($_ -match "^\s*$" -or $_ -match "Inherits.*")
    {
    # Is a blank line
    }
elseif($_ -notmatch "`t")
        {
        # Is a Subject
        Write-Host "Subject: $_ "
        $Subject = $_
        }
elseif($_ -match "`t" -and $_ -notmatch "`t`t")
        {
        # Is a category
        Write-host "Category: $_"
        $category = $_
        }
elseif($_ -match "`t`t")
        {
        # Is a sub-category label
        Write-Host "Label: $_ "
        $label = $_
        }
else
        {
        #Unexpected attribute
        Write-host "Error - unexpected line indentation : $_"
        }
}
```

Comment: I think a good start would be how you want your hashtable to look? Will the titles be the keys, with objects for values, or maybe hashtables for values? Do you want to just make an array of objects with those properties, then sort them based off that? what is the end game here, we need an example of your desired output.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - The most likely requirements are to sort by the Subjects, Categories, and Subcategory labels - since it's a one to many to many relationship I guess the logical structure that comes to mind in an array for the  Subjects, then child arrays for the Categories and Subcategories. Given that I don't have unique "key" values though I'm uncertain if a hashtable is even the right approach (although since I'm going to have search through it, being able to do so without iterating through the array (by using a key) would make things easier).

Comment: Can you give a more accurate example of input? Does it really separate records with '----------------'? Your input example clearly shows dashes where in fact your code references tabs. You say you don't have unique key values, can you update the question to show an example of that?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - sorry about that- in my attempts to format it to make it clear in Stack Overflow's code view I figured swapping the whitespace/tabs into dashes would've helped. I've updated my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your approach and used built-in functionality provided by the `switch` statement:

```
$data = @{}
switch -Regex -File C:\Temp\weirddata.txt
{
    '(^\s*$)|(Inherits)'
    {
        continue
    }

    "^[^`t]"
    {
        $subject = ($PSItem -replace '"').Trim()
        $data[$subject] = @{}
        continue
    }

    "^`t[^`t]"
    {
        $category = ($PSItem -replace '"').Trim()
        $data[$subject][$category] = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@()
        continue
    }

    "^`t`t"
    {
        $label = ($PSItem -replace '"').Trim()
        $data[$subject][$category].Add($label)
        continue
    }

    default
    {
        Write-Warning "No match found for $PSItem"
    }
}

$data
```

It finds everything provided by your example and gets rid of the quotes/whitespace.  It will only fail if you have duplicate subjects, or categories under the same subject.

Comment: That indeed does do the trick for my test data- I'll give it a go against my bigger sample and see if I've got any dodgy duplicates- thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Nice, I thought of the same thing, just wasn't sure if he needed to search for all subjects that have a common something. Like everything that has a SciFi category, or everything that has a UK subcategory, so I wasn't sure how to organize the hashtable. Perhaps I was overthinking it.